# Run Length decompression

Tags: python

Tengo un problema con mi código, se debe de abrir una imagen y descomprimirla utilizando Run Length, sin embargo cuando ejecuto el código, me sale el output vacío. ¿Puedes ayudarme por favor? Muchas gracias.

```
from PIL import Image
import numpy as np
import csv


def decompression(st):
    data = []
    for row in st:
        output = []
        for i, var in enumerate(row):
            if type(var) == str and var.startswith("#"):
                v = var.strip("#")
                output.append(row[i+1] for _ in range(int(v)))
        data.append(output)
    return output


im = np.array(Image.open("atardecer.jpeg").convert("L")) 
with open("atardecer.csv", mode='w', newline='') as f:
    writer = csv.writer(f)
    for line in im:
        writer.writerow(line)


image = decompression(im)

with open("output.csv", mode='w', newline='') as f:
    writer = csv.writer(f)
    for line in image:
        writer.writerow(line)
```

Comment: si sabes que la variable `output` toma el valor de vacio (`[]`) en cada iteracion? mejor inizializalo afuera, junto con `data`

Comment: Sin embargo sigue quedando vacío

Comment: verifica si la condición se cumple